# Error when using phpmailer

Tags: php, cordova, phpmailer

I'm trying to make a phonegap application for ios that will email an html form to me. Im currently hosting the php file on a free web hosting service and whenever I submit the form I get this error:

Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in /home/a2080029/public_html/class.phpmailer.php on line 1302

here's my php:

```
 <?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email_to = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "New customer requesting information/appointment";

    function died($error) {
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
       !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
       !isset($_POST['email']) ||
       !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
       !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
    }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
        return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
    require("PHPMailerAutoload.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587; 
    $mail->Username = "username@gmail.com";  
    $mail->Password = "password";
    $mail->From     = "username@gmail.com";
    $mail->AddAddress("toemail@gmail.com");
    $mail->Subject  = $email_subject;
    $mail->Body     = $email_message;
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo 'Message was not sent.';
        echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent.';
    }?>
```

I have class.phpmailer.php and PHPMailerAutoload.php in the same files as this php file.

I am really new to this whole thing and can't figure out why this wont work for the life of me.

Comment: Sounds like PHPMailer isn't installed correctly, it's missing the SMTP class.

Comment: Thanks for answering, it's installed correctly on my pc, but this is on a web hosting service so t sounds like that could be it, how would I go about getting it installed on there?

Comment: Check with the web hosting provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to install PHPmailer, you just need to copy the class files of the PHPmailer to your server and include then in your code.

Copy the three following files to your server. You can download the files from [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

```
class.phpmailer.php
class.smtp.php
PHPMailerAutoload.php
```

All remaining looks Fine

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't added the class.smtp.php file whoops. Now however when I try to submit the form the page just waits for a while then says error no data received, on to the next problem I guess XD

Comment: there are no such files included on that link