# PHP Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in /home/screcafb/public_html/class.phpmailer.php on line 1520

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am getting the internal server error when I use PHP mailer for sending emails from web page/ I didn't find any solution for that and I don't know how to do configuration of mail in Bigrock server to make PHP mailer work.

Here is the code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
ini_set('SMTP','localhost' ); 
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'example@example.com');
$to="example1@example.com";
$fromrec=$_POST['from'];
$from="example@example.com";
$subject=$_POST['sf'];
$message=$_POST['message'];
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->setFrom($from, 'test');
$mail->addAddress($to);
$mail->Subject  = $subject;
$mail->Body     = "From:".$fromrec."".$message;
if(!$mail->send()) {
 echo 'Message was not sent.';
 echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
 echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
}
?>
```

The error in the log is:

> [30-May-2017 19:08:10 Etc/GMT] PHP Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in /home/screcafb/public_html/class.phpmailer.php on line 1520

Comment: Check the server log, it will show the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You have the call

```
$mail->isSMTP();
```

before you've assigned a value to the variable `$mail`. You need to move that after

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Even after modifying I'm getting same internal server error

Comment: You probably have a syntax error somewhere. What does the server error log say?

Comment: [30-May-2017 19:08:10 Etc/GMT] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SMTP' not found in /home/screcafb/public_html/class.phpmailer.php on line 1520
It is the error in error log

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832007/error-when-using-phpmailer) help?

Comment: Thank you so much errors are rectified but i didn't get mail

Comment: Good for you. I hope you understand the error message, since I can't guess what it is.